# Hide other operator for some time

Tags: c++

Having read about rules of names lookups, overloads resolutions a dozen of times I still feel being confused.

I'm not sure that I ask what I really should have asked but anyway.
Imagine that I have some 3rd-party provided function like this one:

```
namespace some_space {
template<typename Container>
void do_fancy_output(std::ostream& out, const Container& c) {
    for (auto& el : c) { out << el; }
}
} // namespace
```

And imagine that this function ships with ready set of  operator `<<` overloads (for clarity let them be defined in that `some_space` namespace). Besides that, I have my own set of overloads.

The question is: is there any way to switch on and off concrete operator overloads for specific `do_fancy_output()` calls? What are the general architectural guidelines for achieving that?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the 3rd party definition? So that you can use your own?

Comment: So you defined your own overloads, and want to disable them sometimes (despite them being the best match)? If so, I'd recommend not putting your own overloads into the 3rd lib 'some_space', but keep them separate. Let the compiler choose the best match normally, and when you want to use the 3rd lib version, just use the original namespace explicitly.

Comment: If you want to use your own overloads in `do_fancy_output()`, I think you can change the classes in `Container`, though this is somewhat too heavt.

Comment: @HappyCoder, yes, the situation basically is that the function fits my needs but the formatting isn't suitable. So I have to define my own operators. And then I thought that the question is really broader because there may be a hypothetical situation when I will want to use some another operator or the one provideed with library, etc.

Comment: @hauron, Yes, you got the point:)

Answer (score 1):

`operator <<` is a function like any other function. You cannot dynamically change function implementations in runtime.

What you can do is either:

#### use a different function

```
// instead of:
out << el;

// do:
my_left_shift_operation_implementation(out, el);
```

or,

#### make a wrapper

If you *really* like using the `<<` syntax, make your own `class MyElement` which you use to wrap `MyElement(el)` and then define your operator on that type. Then you will have:

```
out << my_el;
```

---

BTW, I would definitely go for the first solution if overriding the operator is the only thing you are after.

### Choosing implementation based on some external factor

If you want to switch between one behaviour and another, do that in your `my_left_shift_operation_implementation`.

You can even make e.g. a `Formatter` class which can be overridden to provide different formatting implementation. Then you'd do:

```
out << my_formatter.format(el);
```

Comment: I wouldn't call operators methods but functions. They can be member functions though, which is the closest thing to methods in C++.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You're right. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack you could use to override the operators called in the function:

- Firstly, you create your own namespace. If you write objects from this namespace, the according operator is first searched in the namespace of this object.
- Secondly, you create functions/operators in that namespace that will output objects as you want.
- Thirdly, you simply create a reference wrapper/proxy in that namespace, which will cause lookup to search the previously written functions first.
- Lastly, and that's a bit trickier, you create a sequence wrapper, which allows iteration like any container but returns reference wrappers instead of the actual objects.

Roughly, the first three steps look like this:

```
namespace special_format
{
    // various functions for writing
    void write(ostream& out, int);
    void write(ostream& out, float);

    // reference wrapper
    template<typename value_type>
    struct ref_wrapper
    {
        value_type const& value;
    };
    // convenience factory function
    template<typename value_type>
    ref_wrapper<value_type>
    ref(value_type const& value)
    {
        ref_wrapper<value_type> r = {value};
        return r;
    }
}
```

I hope that this part is clear. The fourth part with the sequence wrapper is a bit more challenging, because it consists of a few more parts (I'm too lazy and don't want to spoil you the whole fun of writing it). Firstly, in order to support the range-based for loop, you will need to provide begin/end iterator access. One approach is to simply provide plain `begin()` and `end()` functions in the namespace, that will be found when used with types from that namespace. From those, you just return an iterator that wraps the container's iterators. The `value_type`, operator `*` and operator `->` will have to be adjusted to a `ref_wrapper` type, so that the lookup inside our namespace kicks in for those again.